# Magic DNS on Minikube curl(6) cannot resolve host

Tags: curl, dns, minikube, knative

#### I installed Serving on Minikube as instructed by the official documentation.

#### Kourier was chosen as the network layer

### I want to use the Magic DNS on my cluster, I have installed it using

> kubectl apply -f https://github.com/knative/serving/releases/download/knative-v1.0.0/serving-default-domain.yaml

#### And I have  started the tunnel using

> minikube tunnel

#### When  I try to access a service using

> curl "http://greeter-10.default.10.104.139.27.sslip.io"

#### I got  this

> curl: (6) Could not resolve host: greeter-10.default.10.104.139.27.sslip.io;

#### Before that , I deployed a HelloWorld Service on it. And I can access it by temporary DNS with

> curl -H "host: greeter-10.default.example.com" http://10.104.139.27 -v

### Did I miss something?

Answer (score 0):

I would try a `nslookup greeter-10.default.10.104.139.27.sslip.io`, to see what that resolves to on your local setup. From my laptop / using 8.8.8.8, I see that DNS address resolve just fine.